# How do Spanish speakers in majority English-speaking countries recognize each other?

Tags: bilingüismo

I have been to a few stores and restaurants in the US where all employees and most customers are Spanish speakers. As I wait in line, I overhear that all the transactions are in Spanish. When it's my turn and before I say anything, I am initially greeted in English. Since I haven't said anything yet, I know it's not my accent that gave me away as a native English speaker. Are there any other factors like body language or dress that indicate one's first language?

Comment: No se necesita demasiada ciencia para reconocer a los que son ‘de afuera’. Por supuesto, es posible que a ese restaurante suela concurrir la familia del barrio, y por lo tanto ya se conocían los clientes y los empleados, y por eso se hablaban en español. Si querés indagar más en el asunto, publicá una foto tuya de perfil y te digo si tenés cara de no-hispano xd.

Comment: I used to wonder why people in European countries addressed me in English as I did not think I looked stereotypically English. Then I went to the north of Italy and if I did not reply immediately in Italian they switched to German. They are just guessing the most likely language you might speak.

Comment: Es muy probable que no tenga "cara de hispano." ¡Una vez en España un taxista me saludó en alemán! Trabajando cerca de la frontera canadiense, no sé cómo, pero reconocía a todos los clientes de habla francés por su ropa.

Comment: eso son los estereotipos